# solr query in broadleaf

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to Solr and Broadleaf.

I am working in Broadleaf, in that they using the solr search. that's perfectly fine and working condition.
Product table has category field and broadleaf searches by category right now
As per requirement i extend the Product table and make new table with company id, so in my ExtendedProduct table there are two fields companyId and productId(fk with product table)
Now i want to get product list by companyId also.

our schema.xml file looks below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
    <fields>
        <field name="namespace" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="productId" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="category" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="explicitCategory" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="searchable" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_searchable" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />

        <dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_l" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_d" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_p" type="double" indexed="true" stored="false" />

        <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

        <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
        <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
        <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <types>
        <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

        <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
        <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" />

        <!-- Default numeric field types. For faster range queries, consider the 
            tint/tlong/tdouble types. -->
        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />

        <!-- Numeric field types that index each value at various levels of precision 
            to accelerate range queries when the number of values between the range endpoints 
            is large. See the javadoc for NumericRangeQuery for internal implementation 
            details. Smaller precisionStep values (specified in bits) will lead to more 
            tokens indexed per value, slightly larger index size, and faster range queries. 
            A precisionStep of 0 disables indexing at different precision levels. -->
        <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />

        <!-- The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, 
            and is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime 
            http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime The trailing "Z" designates UTC 
            time and is mandatory. Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z 
            All other components are mandatory. Expressions can also be used to denote 
            calculations that should be performed relative to "NOW" to determine the 
            value, ie... NOW/HOUR ... Round to the start of the current hour NOW-1DAY 
            ... Exactly 1 day prior to now NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS ... 6 months and 3 days 
            in the future from the start of the current day Consult the DateField javadocs 
            for more information. Note: For faster range queries, consider the tdate 
            type -->
        <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />

        <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
        <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" />

        <!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic cross-language defaults: 
            it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer and down cases. -->
        <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>

    </types>
</schema>
```

and solrConfig.xml files looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <abortOnConfigurationError>${solr.abortOnConfigurationError:true} </abortOnConfigurationError>
    <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_40</luceneMatchVersion>
    <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}" />
    <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2" />

    <query>
        <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>

        <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />
        <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />
        <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />

        <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>

        <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
        <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>

        <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener" />
        <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
            <arr name="queries">
                <lst>
                    <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </listener>

        <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
        <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
    </query>

    <requestDispatcher>
        <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" />
        <httpCaching never304="true" />
    </requestDispatcher>

    <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <int name="rows">4</int>
            <str name="df">name_t</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>

    <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
    <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
    <requestHandler name="/update/json" class="solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />

    <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
        <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
    </queryResponseWriter>

</config>
```

Right now in broadleaf they are placing query for category:2023.
below are the SolrQuery.toString looks like
    q=category%3A2003&fl=id&rows=15&fq=namespace%3Ad&start=0

I still can't find out how/where table name is configured into this.

I want to find product by companyId also, which change should i make to do this ?

Thanks in advance,
Ankit

Answer (score 3):

The main documentation link for this is at http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/Catalog-and-Search.html.

The salient points of this are copied below:

> Dynamic fields
>
> These fields are specified by the user via database entries in
>   blc_field and blc_field_search_types. Before we talk about what
>   exactly goes in a Field, we must first cover what a dynamic field in
>   Solr is. If you open up schema.xml, you will see a listing of many
>   different fields. A short excerpt follows:
>
> Here, we're defining a few dynamic
>   fields. For example, if we were to create a field that was called
>   manufactuer_s, it would be indexed by Solr as a Solr.StrField.
>
> Another important distinction is between two properties in FieldImpl:
>   searchableFieldTypes and facetFieldType. Searchable field types will
>   be built into the Solr index, of which you may have multiple types.
>   For example, you might want to index a field as both a String field
>   and a Text field (text fields allow partial matches). However, you
>   would only want to facet on the String field. The Broadleaf Field
>   implementation gives you this freedom. Note, also, that the facet
>   field also controls the Solr index to use for sorting.
>
> As a quick example, let's take a look at what might happen if we have
>   the following fields defined:
>
> manufacturer, facetFieldType: "s", searchableFieldTypes: { "s", "t" }
>   defaultSku.retailPrice, facetFieldType: "d" defaultSku.name,
>   facetField: "s", searchableFieldTypes: { "s", "t" } and we index a
>   sample product. A suitable Solr representation in JSON would be:
>
> {    id                       : 100,   category                 :
>   [2000, 2002],   manufacturer_s           : "Spice Exchange",
>   manufacturer_t           : "Spice Exchange",
>   defaultSku.retailPrice_d : 6.99,   defaultSku.name_s        : "Day of
>   the Dead Scotch Bonnet Hot Sauce",   defaultSku.name_t        : "Day
>   of the Dead Scotch Bonnet Hot Sauce",   searchable               :
>   "Spice Exchange Day of the Dead Scotch Bonnet Hot Sauce" }
>
> You might be wondering what that searchable field is. When you specify a Field
>   as searchable, we will copy the Field's value into the solr index
>   field searchable. When we do queries later on, they will be against
>   this field.
>
> We'll get back to this shortly and see how sorting, searching and
>   faceting would work against this product.

So basically, you define an entry into BLC_FIELD (which is the FieldImpl Java class) that has 'companyId' for the propertyName field. From load_catalog_data.sql in your project, this is how the 'manufacturer' field is imported to be searched on:

```
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, FACET_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1, 'PRODUCT', 'manufacturer', 'mfg', 1, 's');
```

Comment: Hi phillipuniverse,

Thanks for your reply, that really helpful. Right now i put new entry in shema.xml for companyId 
<field name="companyId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />

and storing this into solr index while server is starting. and its working fine right now..

As we can change the things by extending in site, do we change the things in admin also as per requirement ?

Right now i am using broadleaf 3.0 workspace and demo-site doesn't give any code for admin, If i want to trace some flow by code , how can i do that ?