# Search Not working - Broadleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, solr, broadleaf-commerce

I have setup the demo of Broadleaf-3.1 and have created a totally new database  with 100+ categories and 2500+ products. 
I want to configure the Index and search for following fields :-

- blc_category.NAME
- blc_product.MANUFACTURE
- blc_product.MODEL
- blc_sku.NAME
- blc_sku.LONG DESCRIPTION

Can someone tell me what is the entry that will go in :-

- blc_field
- blc_field_search_types
- blc_search_facet
- blc_cat_search_facet_xref
  and any other table.

I have gone through the document link and try inputting the values, but sadly nothing works.

But still it still doesn't return any value on search . Also, for products under the category the sorting based on Name or anything else is also not working.

I am new to this Solr thing and a detailed answer would help.

Thanks in advance.

- Sumit

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, [Rest API - NullPointerException in Broadleaf Commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461560/rest-api-nullpointerexception-in-broadleaf-commerce/32985277#32985277)

For the fields you have mentions, add above entries in database,

```
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, FACET_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1, 'PRODUCT', 'manufacturer', 'mfg', TRUE, 's');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, TRANSLATABLE, FACET_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2, 'PRODUCT', 'defaultSku.name', 'name', TRUE, TRUE, 's');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, FACET_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (3, 'PRODUCT', 'model', 'model', TRUE, 's');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, TRANSLATABLE) VALUES (4, 'PRODUCT', 'defaultSku.longDescription', 'ldesc', TRUE, TRUE);
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD (FIELD_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, PROPERTY_NAME, ABBREVIATION, SEARCHABLE, FACET_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (5, 'PRODUCT', 'defaultCategory.name', 'categoryName', TRUE, 's');

INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD_SEARCH_TYPES (FIELD_ID, SEARCHABLE_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (1, 't');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD_SEARCH_TYPES (FIELD_ID, SEARCHABLE_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (2, 't');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD_SEARCH_TYPES (FIELD_ID, SEARCHABLE_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (3, 't');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD_SEARCH_TYPES (FIELD_ID, SEARCHABLE_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (4, 't');
INSERT INTO BLC_FIELD_SEARCH_TYPES (FIELD_ID, SEARCHABLE_FIELD_TYPE) VALUES (5, 't');

INSERT INTO BLC_SEARCH_FACET (SEARCH_FACET_ID, FIELD_ID, LABEL, SHOW_ON_SEARCH, MULTISELECT, SEARCH_DISPLAY_PRIORITY) VALUES (1, 1, 'Manufacturer', FALSE, TRUE, 0);
INSERT INTO BLC_SEARCH_FACET (SEARCH_FACET_ID, FIELD_ID, LABEL, SHOW_ON_SEARCH, MULTISELECT, SEARCH_DISPLAY_PRIORITY) VALUES (2, 5, 'categoryName', FALSE, TRUE, 0);
```